# Seg fault with compute shader in QML

Tags: qt, qml, compute-shader

How can I track down a seg fault in a mostly QML app?

The specific error is: `*** Error in 'app/app': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00007ff4bce5e710 ***`

It only happens when I have a `ComputeCommand` (shown below.)  The error it self is intermittent. This is using Qt 5.7.1 (same happens in Qt 5.8.0 with Ubuntu 16.04) on Ubuntu 14.04.03 built with clang.  In debug mode (with gdb) I don't get anything useful (see below), simply that something happened in my app, then a bunch of Qt3DRender libs with no symbol info.  Valgrind and Hellgrind slow the app too much to use it (this app visualizes 100s of thousands of points, and I can't provoke the problem at really low point counts), ASAN and TSAN do report problems, but without symbols/line numbers I can't track anything down.

My setup is `main.qml` -> `Scene3d` -> `RenderSettings`, `Entity`

I use a custom buffer and geometry I wrote (`PointBuffer`, `PointGeometry`) I wrote but didn't include.  They inherit from `QBuffer` and `QGeomotry` respectively.

Essentially, when the compute shader is activated (a `ComputeCommand` component on the entity, and a `DispatchCompute` on `viewport`), I get the intermittent seg fault above.  The only asynchronous component I've added is that my buffer gets written to by my own thread, I've surrounded this by a `std::mutex`, but I don't think this is the problem as I don't see any mutexes in the `QBuffer` or `QGeometry` code.

The shader itself creates a coherent buffer (`layout (std430, binding = 0) coherent buffer Particles`), but otherwise just reads in and prints out the points; and worked when I had no operations in it .. until the seg fault of course.

My question, have I configured the Compute Shader poorly?  Or is there a better way to debug this?

The most I can trace the problem is that it only happens after a buffer refresh on the geometry.

**RenderSettings**:

```
RenderSettings {
    property CameraSet cameraSet

    property real userViewWidth: 0.79
    property real topOrthoViewHeight: 0.79

    activeFrameGraph: Viewport {
        id: viewport
        normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)

        RenderSurfaceSelector {
            ClearBuffers {
                buffers:    ClearBuffers.ColorDepthBuffer

                NoDraw {}
            }

            // Compute Pass
            DispatchCompute {
                workGroupX: 1024; workGroupY: 1; workGroupZ: 1
                TechniqueFilter {
                    matchAll: [
                        FilterKey { name: "type"; value: "compute" }
                    ]
                }
            }

            Viewport {
                id: userViewport
                normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0, 0, 0.5, 1.0)

                CameraSelector {
                    id: userCameraSelectorViewport
                    camera: cameraSet.user.camera
                }
            }

            // Second and third viewport...
        }
    }
}
```

**Material** (`PointMaterial`)

```
Material {
    property PointBuffer dataBuffer;

    ShaderProgram {
        id: computeShader
        computeShaderCode:  loadSource("qrc:/shaders/pointcloud.comp")
    }

    ShaderProgram {
        id: drawShader
        vertexShaderCode:   loadSource("qrc:/shaders/pointcloud.vert")
        fragmentShaderCode: loadSource("qrc:/shaders/pointcloud.frag")
    }

    effect: Effect {
        techniques: [
            Technique {
                renderPasses: [
                    RenderPass {
                        shaderProgram: computeShader
                        parameters: [
                            // Point buffer
                            Parameter { name: "Particles"; value: dataBuffer }
                        ]
                    }
                ] // renderpasses
                filterKeys: [
                    FilterKey { name: "type"; value: "compute" }
                ]
                graphicsApiFilter {
                    api: GraphicsApiFilter.OpenGL
                    profile: GraphicsApiFilter.CoreProfile
                    majorVersion: 4
                    minorVersion: 3
                }
            },
            Technique {
                renderPasses: [
                    RenderPass {
                        shaderProgram: drawShader
                        renderStates: [
                            PointSize { sizeMode: PointSize.Programmable }
                        ]
                        parameters: [
                            Parameter { name: "pointSize"; value: 0.4 }
                        ]
                    }
                ] // renderPasses
                filterKeys: [
                    FilterKey { name: "type"; value: "draw" }
                ]
                graphicsApiFilter {
                    api: GraphicsApiFilter.OpenGL
                    profile: GraphicsApiFilter.CoreProfile
                    majorVersion: 4
                    minorVersion: 3
                }
            } // technique
        ] // techniques
    }
}
```

**Entity**:

```
Entity {
    property PointBuffer buffer: PointBuffer {
        id: pointBuffer
        type: Buffer.VertexBuffer
    }

    PointsMaterial {
        id: pointsMaterial
        dataBuffer: pointBuffer
    }

    Entity {
        property GeometryRenderer pointRenderer: GeometryRenderer {
            instanceCount: 1 // How many times to run this geometry, since we write
                             // all points in the buffer once, only call this once.
            primitiveType: GeometryRenderer.Points
            geometry: PointGeometry { buffer: pointBuffer }
        }

        // https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.7/qml-computecommand.html
        property ComputeCommand computeCommand: ComputeCommand {
            workGroupX: 1024; workGroupY: 1; workGroupZ: 1
        }

        components: [ pointRenderer, computeCommand, pointsMaterial ]
    }
}
```

I tried to limit the amount of code I posted to keep the question small, but I'm happy to add anything else if it'll help solve the issue.

My (gdb) debugger output from the main thread is:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fff9e9cc700 (LWP 8208)]
0x00007ffff33e058c in ?? () from /opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt53DRender.so.5
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff33e058c in ?? () from /opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt53DRender.so.5
#1  0x00007ffff33e6619 in ?? () from /opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt53DRender.so.5
#2  0x00007ffff338fe05 in Qt3DRender::Render::Renderer::performCompute(Qt3DRender::Render::RenderView const*, Qt3DRender::Render::RenderCommand*) () from /opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt53DRender.so.5
#3  0x00007ffff3392610 in Qt3DRender::Render::Renderer::executeCommandsSubmission(Qt3DRender::Render::RenderView const*) () from /opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt53DRender.so.5
#4  0x00007ffff3392b14 in Qt3DRender::Render::Renderer::submitRenderViews(QVector<Qt3DRender::Render::RenderView*> const&) () from /opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt53DRender.so.5
#5  0x00007ffff3394bf2 in Qt3DRender::Render::Renderer::doRender() ()
   from /opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt53DRender.so.5
#6  0x00007fffc723a806 in ?? () from /opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Scene3D/libqtquickscene3dplugin.so
#7  0x00007ffff1f56e3d in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) ()
   from /opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007ffff3ef865e in QQuickWindowPrivate::renderSceneGraph(QSize const&) ()
   from /opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5
#9  0x00007ffff3ecabd1 in ?? () from /opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5
#10 0x00007ffff3ecbe58 in ?? () from /opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5
#11 0x00007ffff1d68539 in ?? () from /opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#12 0x00007ffff0eb3184 in start_thread (arg=0x7fff9e9cc700) at pthread_create.c:312
#13 0x00007ffff11c337d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
```

### Update

Pretty sure I've narrowed this down to a race condition.  I've eliminated other libraries I was using that I thought could be causing an issue, and nothing.  Basically, the combination of a compute filter and the buffer getting re-written asynchronously leads to this seg fault.  I'm not sure if there's some way to protect this with a mutex.  Right now I'm looking to see if I can re-write my Entity in C++ to gain greater control over how the compute shader is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the cause of the seg fault here is a result of how I was updating my buffer.  In my `PointBuffer`, I had an asynchronous task which was calling `Qt3DRender::QBuffer::setData(new_data)` where `new_data` was a `QByteArray`.

To set the data, I was creating a `QByteArray` on the stack, copying my data to it, and then setting my data with `Qt3DRender::QBuffer::setData(my_qbyte_array)`

This had the effect of exposing my stack variable to the rest of the app, which when deleted, lead to the seg fault.

Instead I changed this to:

```
Qt3DRender::QBuffer::setData(
   QByteArray::fromRawData(
      reinterpret_cast<const char*>(points_.linearize()),
      sizeof(PointType) * pointCount
   )
)
```

This instead points to my original data (so no need for a bug copy) and doesn't bind to any temporary data.

Another solution I used though which I mentioned, uses Qt 5.8.0's new 
`QBuffer::updateData`<sup>[docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qbuffer.html#setData)</sup> function.  With this, I created a local `QByteArray`, but then copied it into my current data.  This has problems (specifically with sizing) and is less efficient, but I thought I'd still mention it.

Comment: Let's say if you are updating only a part of the entire array, isn't updateData more efficient than setData which copies entire data(even with implicit shared data, due to copy-on-write a deep copy would occur when writing to the copied data)?